# Determine whether sql table contains a specific entry when grouping by something else

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm developing an application in which users can sign up for races. I have simplified my scenario significantly for this question, and a SQL Fiddle [is available here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2e5bd/1).

```
SELECT r.date AS raceDate, count(s.userId) AS numSignups FROM signup AS s
INNER JOIN race AS r ON r.id = s.raceId
GROUP BY s.raceId
```

What I am trying to do is to select a column in my query which determines whether the user of the application has signed up for the particular race, i.e. an own column 'signedUp' which contains true/false for every tuple. The id of the application's user is available as a constant.

Thanks for any feedback :)

Comment: What are your desired results on the fiddle you provided?  Not sure I completely understand your question.

Comment: Lets say Barack Obama is using the application. I want a separate column in the result that says whether he (Barack) has signed up for the race or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `OUTER JOIN` on the table and then add a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT r.date AS raceDate, 
  count(s.userId) AS numSignups,
  case when u.id is null then 0 else 1 end as Enrolled
FROM signup AS s
  INNER JOIN race AS r ON r.id = s.raceId
  LEFT JOIN user u on s.userid = u.id and u.name = 'Barack Obama'
GROUP BY s.raceId
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2e5bd/5)